# Despite the alleged boom in Vinyl, almost no physical record shops in cities. Is it all just eCommerce?

Tags: vinyl

I have also recently acquired a vinyl player. I thought there were a lot of people who wanted to go back to analogue in a digital world. I read in the press about a vinyl boom.

I was totally surprised that there are no or only very small record shops in larger cities (e.g. Switzerland). Do all analogue lovers buy online?

Online, the selection of records is very large and varied, but physical shops are very limited and small.

Comment: They're coming - https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-london-65417131

Comment: You will not likely be able to sell vinyl to those who see no nostalgic value in it, or who like retro fashion. Personally I see no boom, just a hype. Very likely started by the record companies who've noticed that people have no use for them any longer in the current millennium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a function of where you live. In my city (Columbus, Ohio, a mid-sized city in the United States Midwest) there are a large number of small independent record shops, many of which are new within the last ten years since the vinyl revival started.

However, it may also be a function of your expectations. At one time, vinyl was the dominant way of recording music, so there were large record stores everywhere. The rebirth of vinyl, as with many other "obsolete" technologies, has been as a niche boutique product for collectors. So you won't probably ever see the return of big-box record stores, only little mom-and-pop storefronts with specialized selections.

I personally try to buy my vinyl exclusively from small independent stores. But that works better for browsing. If you have a specific title you definitely want, it might be unlikely to show up locally--or at least be subject to the luck-of-the-draw.